# Add Php variable to new Date()

Tags: javascript, php

I want to add my php variable that contains the date to this code: new Date($mydate) If not possible to use my php variable how do I add my own date to this code. My date comes from SQL database and then displayed in a php variable.

```
var countDownDate = new Date("august 8, 2020 15:37:25").getTime();
```

Comment: Is this JavaScript code in a `.php` file?  What happens when you try to output a value from PHP like any other time you output a value from PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass the `PHP` variable as parameter to the `JavaScript` Object:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
<?php $date = "07/08/2020"; ?>
<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $date; ?>").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks  for the echo php variable in the date brackets i will try that  and respond

Comment: Sure. It's the same thing as the program you're trying to implement. Just make sure it's in a ``.php`` file.

Comment: this is my date:  <?php

$date = (07/08/2020);

?>

Comment: @kumbi put it in a string as follows: ``<?php $date = "07/08/2020"; ?>``

Comment: got this error "  
Warning: Division by zero in /Library/WebServer/Documents/test2.php on line 17

NaNd NaNh NaNm NaNs "       lol...   I googled that error and its because of echoing php in the date field.

Comment: @kumbi you are doing something wrong. I updated the answer with your demo.

Comment: wait it works as long as my custom date field  is in format:  $date = ("aug 7,2020");   THANKS Majed